# How to set up two machines for a cluster with two nodes on each machine

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two dedicated machines for ES (2.2.0). The two machines have the same specs. Each runs on a Windows Server 2012 R2 and has 128GB memory. Regarding ES, I plan to have TWO nodes on each machine for the cluster.

I am looking at elasticsearch.yml to see how to configure each node to form a cluster.

The two machines on the same network with the following server names and IP addresses:

```
SRC01, 172.21.0.21
SRC02, 172.21.0.22
```

I am looking at elasticsearch.yml and I am not sure how to set things up. I guess that I need set proper values for Network and Discovery sections in elasticsearch.yml:

```
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
# network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
# http.port: 9200
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Elasticsearch nodes will find each other via unicast, by default.
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
# discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of nodes / 2 + 1):
#
# discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
```

I searched on the net and SO and hoped to find a complete config example for me to start, but failed to find one.

### Update

With Val's help, here is the minimum elasticsearch.yml that I have on the four nodes (2 one each machine) after tests:

```
#----------SRC01, node 1---------
cluster.name: elastic
node.name: elastic_src01_1
network.host: 172.21.0.21
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.21.0.21","172.21.0.22"]


#----------SRC01, node 2---------
cluster.name: elastic
node.name: elastic_src01_2
network.host: 172.21.0.21
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.21.0.21","172.21.0.22"]


#----------SRC02, node 1---------
cluster.name: elastic
node.name: elastic_src02_1
network.host: 172.21.0.22
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.21.0.21","172.21.0.22"]


#----------SRC02, node 2---------
cluster.name: elastic
node.name: elastic_src02_2
network.host: 172.21.0.22
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.21.0.21","172.21.0.22"]
```

Here is the questions I got:

1. I started Node elastic_src01_1 and then Node elastic_src01_2 and they are on the same machine. When starting elastic_src01_2, I am able to see ES-generated messages the following (**detected_master**)

Logs excerpt:

```
[2016-02-28 12:38:33,155][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic_src01_2] version[2.2.0], pid[4620], build[8ff36d1/2016-01-27T13:32:39Z]
[2016-02-28 12:38:33,155][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic_src01_2] initializing ...
[2016-02-28 12:38:33,546][INFO ][plugins                  ] [elastic_src01_2] modules [lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2016-02-28 12:38:33,562][INFO ][env                      ] [elastic_src01_2] using [1] data paths, mounts [[Data (E:)]], net usable_space [241.7gb],
net total_space [249.9gb], spins? [unknown], types [NTFS]
[2016-02-28 12:38:33,562][INFO ][env                      ] [elastic_src01_2] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-02-28 12:38:35,077][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic_src01_2] initialized
[2016-02-28 12:38:35,077][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic_src01_2] starting ...
[2016-02-28 12:38:35,218][INFO ][transport                ] [elastic_src01_2] publish_address {172.21.0.21:9302}, bound_addresses {172.21.0.21:9302}
[2016-02-28 12:38:35,218][INFO ][discovery                ] [elastic_src01_2] elastic/N8r-gD9WQSSvAYMOlJzmIg
[2016-02-28 12:38:39,796][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [elastic_src01_2] detected_master {elastic_src01_1}{UWGAo0BKTQm2f650nyDKYg}{172.21.0.21}{1
72.21.0.21:9300}, added {{elastic_src01_1}{UWGAo0BKTQm2f650nyDKYg}{172.21.0.21}{172.21.0.21:9300},{elastic_src01_1}{qNDQjkmsRjiIVjZ88JsX4g}{172.21.0.2
1}{172.21.0.21:9301},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [{elastic_src01_1}{UWGAo0BKTQm2f650nyDKYg}{172.21.0.21}{172.21.0.21:9300}])
[2016-02-28 12:38:39,843][INFO ][http                     ] [elastic_src01_2] publish_address {172.21.0.21:9202}, bound_addresses {172.21.0.21:9202}
[2016-02-28 12:38:39,843][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic_src01_2] started
```

However, when I started Node 1 on SRC02 machine, I am not seeing **detected_master** message. Here is what ES generates:

```
[2016-02-28 12:22:52,256][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic_src02_1] version[2.2.0], pid[6432], build[8ff36d1/2016-01-27T13:32:39Z]
[2016-02-28 12:22:52,256][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic_src02_1] initializing ...
[2016-02-28 12:22:52,662][INFO ][plugins                  ] [elastic_src02_1] modules [lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2016-02-28 12:22:52,693][INFO ][env                      ] [elastic_src02_1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[Data (E:)]], net usable_space [241.6gb], net total_
space [249.8gb], spins? [unknown], types [NTFS]
[2016-02-28 12:22:52,693][INFO ][env                      ] [elastic_src02_1] heap size [910.5mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-02-28 12:22:54,193][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic_src02_1] initialized
[2016-02-28 12:22:54,193][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic_src02_1] starting ...
[2016-02-28 12:22:54,334][INFO ][transport                ] [elastic_src02_1] publish_address {172.21.0.22:9300}, bound_addresses {172.21.0.22:9300}
[2016-02-28 12:22:54,334][INFO ][discovery                ] [elastic_src02_1] elastic/SNvuAfnxQV-RW430zLF6Vg
[2016-02-28 12:22:58,912][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [elastic_src02_1] new_master {elastic_src02_1}{SNvuAfnxQV-RW430zLF6Vg}{172.21.0.22}{172.21.0.22:9300
}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-02-28 12:22:58,943][INFO ][gateway                  ] [elastic_src02_1] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2016-02-28 12:22:58,959][INFO ][http                     ] [elastic_src02_1] publish_address {172.21.0.22:9200}, bound_addresses {172.21.0.22:9200}
[2016-02-28 12:22:58,959][INFO ][node                     ] [elastic_src02_1] started
```

Does the node on the SRC02 machine really form a cluster with nodes on the SRC01 machine?

2. On the same machine (SRC01), if I add

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3

to the elasticsearch.yml file of Node elastic_src01_1, elastic_src01_2,
then when starting the second node elastic_src01_2 on machine SRC01, I am unable to see **detected_master** in ES-generated messages.

Does this mean elastic_src01_1 and elastic_src01_2 not form a cluster?

### Update 2

The SRC01 and SRC02 machines can see each other. Here are ping results from SRC02 to SRC01:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ping 172.21.0.21

Pinging 172.21.0.21 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.21.0.21: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.21.0.21: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.21.0.21: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.21.0.21: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

### Update 3

The problem is resolved. The reason that my setup was not working before is the server's firewall prevented port 9300/9200 for communication.

Comment: Can you make sure the logs you pasted are really from the machine you think they come from. It seems in your question 1, the logs don't match with what you're describing, i.e. "When starting elastic_src01_2 ..." while the logs shown are for `[elastic_src02_2]`. A simple way to see what nodes are in your cluster is to use the [`/_cat/nodes` command](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html)

Comment: Val, sorry for the copy and paste typo. I just posted the full messages when node elastic_src01_2 is started.

Comment: Are you sure both machines see each other? i.e. can you ping 172.21.0.21 from 172.21.0.22 and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, they can see each other. Ping results  from 172.21.0.22.are posted as example.

Comment: Val, thanks for helping me. One piece of info: SRC01 is a virtual server sits in one Dell box, and SRC02 on another physical box. Not sure whether this info is useful.

Comment: Val, I did another config change test. Please see Update 3.

Comment: The hosts list needs to contain either IP addresses or resolvable host names, src01/src02 are probably not a valid host names (unless you add them to your `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you simply need to configure the network settings to make sure that all nodes can see each other on the network. Additionally, since you're running two nodes on the same machine and you still want high availability, you want to prevent a primary shard and its replica to land on the same physical machine.

Finally, since you'll have a total of four nodes in your cluster, you'll want to [prevent split brain situations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/modules-node.html#split-brain), so you need to set `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` as well.

Node 1/2 on SRC01:

```
# cluster name
cluster.name: Name_of_your_cluster

# Give each node a different name (optional but good practice if you don't know Marvel characters)
node.name: SRC01_Node1/2

# The IP that this node will bind to and publish
network.host: 172.21.0.21

# The IP of the other nodes
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.21.0.22"]

# prevent split brain
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3    

# to prevent primary/replica shards to be on the same physical host 
# see why at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677741/proper-value-of-es-heap-size-for-a-dedicated-machine-with-two-nodes-in-a-cluster
cluster.routing.allocation.same_shard.host: true

# prevent memory swapping
bootstrap.mlockall: true
```

Node 1/2 on SRC02:

```
# cluster name
cluster.name: Name_of_your_cluster

# Give each node a different name (optional but good practice if you don't know Marvel characters)
node.name: SRC02_Node1/2

# The IP that this node will bind to and publish
network.host: 172.21.0.22

# The IP of the other nodes
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.21.0.21"]

# prevent split brain
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3    

# to prevent primary/replica shards to be on the same physical host 
# see why at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677741/proper-value-of-es-heap-size-for-a-dedicated-machine-with-two-nodes-in-a-cluster
cluster.routing.allocation.same_shard.host: true

# prevent memory swapping
bootstrap.mlockall: true
```

Comment: Val, it seems discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts should contain both machines, not just the other machine. Otherwise, the second node  would not be able find the first node on the same machine. That is why I have: discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.21.0.21","172.21.0.22"]

Comment: No it's ok, you can do both, either only the other node or both. But agreed it's a good practice to add all nodes to that list because it's easier to manage multi-nodes configurations.

Comment: Val, in my case, without 172.21.0.21 (SRC01), the second node on SRC01 is not able to have the "detected_master" message at star