# Proper way to add a second master node to an existing elasticsearch node

Tags: elasticsearch, pelias

I have two identical servers, I have setup elastic search on one and imported about 200m records into it. I now want the other server to have the same set of records and the two to work as a pair, just incase one server goes down I can quickly remove the one from the cluster and it will just work, no new data is inserted its just read. I followed the information I have found online and setup my hosts to find each other. It just seems like the indexes are not transferring over to the other server I see in the status of the shards that they are replicating, but they never increase in size in the data directory.

I have used this as a pointer.

[How to add a new node to my Elasticsearch cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717790/how-to-add-a-new-node-to-my-elasticsearch-cluster)

My question is can I just scp copy over the 300gb plus of data to the data directory or does elasticsearch need to do that?

Debug Info

```
curl 192.168.1.1:9200/_cat/recovery?v
index  shard time   type       stage source_host target_host repository snapshot files files_percent bytes       bytes_percent total_files total_bytes translog translog_percent total_translog
pelias 0     248094 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        76          13092952848 0        100.0%           0
pelias 0     333911 relocation index 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 n/a        n/a      76    76.3%         13092952848 9.6%          76          13092952848 0        100.0%           0
pelias 1     248053 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        70          12924273847 0        100.0%           0
pelias 1     333915 relocation index 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 n/a        n/a      70    98.6%         12924273847 98.0%         70          12924273847 0        100.0%           0
pelias 2     246409 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        88          13122252645 0        100.0%           0
pelias 3     247434 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        89          13020268507 0        100.0%           0
pelias 4     247109 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        91          13173644369 0        100.0%           0
pelias 5     247574 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        85          13133234395 0        100.0%           0
pelias 6     245236 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        82          12882617780 0        100.0%           0
pelias 7     246530 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        86          13098807983 0        100.0%           0
pelias 8     245089 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        73          12963045661 0        100.0%           0
pelias 9     245149 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        94          13072471481 0        100.0%           0
pelias 10    248994 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        85          12950316547 0        100.0%           0
pelias 11    247667 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        73          13329893241 0        100.0%           0
pelias 12    248055 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        79          12930959145 0        100.0%           0
pelias 13    249255 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        106         11586141290 0        100.0%           0
pelias 14    247759 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        82          15107208138 0        100.0%           0
pelias 15    247888 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        79          13112198101 0        100.0%           0
pelias 16    247675 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        91          14672189956 0        100.0%           0
pelias 17    247205 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        73          13048452056 0        100.0%           0
pelias 18    246910 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        82          13095873096 0        100.0%           0
pelias 19    246325 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        70          15019530308 0        100.0%           0
pelias 20    247924 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        77          12898451788 0        100.0%           0
pelias 21    248663 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        76          13035468700 0        100.0%           0
pelias 22    249105 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        95          13045543380 0        100.0%           0
pelias 23    246119 store      done  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 n/a        n/a      0     100.0%        0           100.0%        79          13052787518 0        100.0%           0



     curl 192.168.1.1:9200/_cat/shards?v
index  shard prirep state          docs  store ip          node
pelias 22    p      STARTED    21505006 12.1gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 5     p      STARTED    21503012 12.2gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 2     p      STARTED    21499705 12.2gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 15    p      STARTED    21504176 12.2gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 4     p      STARTED    21512286 12.2gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 16    p      STARTED    21508361 13.6gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 20    p      STARTED    21499566   12gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 6     p      STARTED    21504264 11.9gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 14    p      STARTED    21511288   14gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 23    p      STARTED    21513431 12.1gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 13    p      STARTED    21505815 10.7gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 12    p      STARTED    21506998   12gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 10    p      STARTED    21511704   12gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 9     p      STARTED    21504736 12.1gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 1     p      RELOCATING 21506366   12gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02 -> 192.168.1.1 PsmIinmpQ5myXE5oNdw4qA ronin-tile01
pelias 7     p      STARTED    21508186 12.1gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 21    p      STARTED    21511618 12.1gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 17    p      STARTED    21511014 12.1gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 18    p      STARTED    21512577 12.1gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 8     p      STARTED    21511765   12gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 11    p      STARTED    21504697 12.4gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 3     p      STARTED    21509465 12.1gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 19    p      STARTED    21503146 13.9gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02
pelias 0     p      RELOCATING 21512876 12.1gb 192.168.1.2 ronin-tile02 -> 192.168.1.1 PsmIinmpQ5myXE5oNdw4qA ronin-tile01

  curl 192.168.1.1:9200/_cat/indices?v
health status index  pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   pelias  24   0  516182058           89    295.5gb        295.5gb
```

Comment: Provided you've set everything up correctly, ES will do that for you, no need to scp anything. Can you provide the output you get from `curl localhost:9200/_cat/recovery`, `curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices` and `curl localhost:9200/_cat/shards` ?

Comment: I updated the question with the output

Comment: Sorry, do you mind appending `?v` to the URLs so we have the headers as well

Comment: No problem done

Comment: It looks like they are moving this time, just slowly. Watching in cerebro they are not jumping back and fourth between two shards for relocation.

Comment: Yeah, 13GB shards take a bit of time to move around, depending on the size and contention of your network pipe

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong here.

Comment: Sounds good, I don't know why yesterday it was having issues transferring it just kept bouncing between shards and not moving them.

Answer (score 0):

In order to duplicate data between two (or more) Elasticsearch nodes, you need to add [replicas](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/replica-shards.html). For your index (`pelias`) and your host (`192.168.1.1:9200`), you can add a single replica with the following `curl` command:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://192.168.1.1:9200/pelias/_settings' -d '{
  "index": {
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  }
}'
```

By the way, thanks for using [Pelias](http://github.com/pelias/pelias/), I'm one of the core maintainers :)

I also maintain a set of bash scripts to accomplish common Elasticsearch tasks [here](https://github.com/orangejulius/elasticsearch-bash-utils). There is a script specifically for [adding replicas](https://github.com/orangejulius/elasticsearch-bash-utils/blob/master/add_replica.sh) that you or others might find useful.

Comment: HI, @orangejulius 
is it possible to transfer some files from the indexer machine to the host server (once) because the indexer machine is my PC ?