# Adding new node to elasticsearch cluster created through docker-compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I created a simple elasticsearch "cluster" on my local machine (mac) using docker-compose. The config is seen below

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
    environment:
      - cluster.name=elasticsearch
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "index.number_of_replicas: 1"
      - "index.number_of_shards: 2"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Now I would like to add a new es node to this cluster, but I am not sure how to proceed. I have tried to run a docker container with the command:

```
docker run -e "cluster.name=elasticsearch" -e "bootstrap.memory_lock: true" -e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" -e "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=localhost:9200" -e "network.host: _local_"  -v esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
```

But this seems to create a separate cluster/node because when I try and access `http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/health?pretty` I still see only one node:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 1,
  "active_shards" : 1,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

I'm not sure how else I should create the new es node and add it to my cluster. Do I need to use docker-compose again or are the flags that I specified in my `docker run` incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

According to this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html
article in elastic website, you should specify the name of cluster, name of discovery seed host to each elastic instance.

```yaml
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.3
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.3
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic
  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.3
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [official doc of Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html)

you need to specify the nodes in your docker-compose.yml file like here:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Comment: If i run the compose file with the second node config it works fine, I already tried that with the example yaml in the elasticsearch docs. But I wanted to know how I would add a node after the cluster is already running

Comment: take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44483173/7307093)