# Moving to distributed Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, nodes, cluster-computing, elasticsearch-5

I have already elasticsearch installed in standalone mode , in 1 node cluster.
I created many Elasticsearch indexes for analysis on kibana.
Now I wanna switch it to distributed cluster of 3 node cluster !

I wonder if that will cause the delete of elasticsearch indexes???

is it that the old data stored on elasticsearch will stay safe on the node 1 only or it will be distributed on 3 nodes ???

please don't hesitate for help !!

best regards !!

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

Elasticsearch is built to be distributed, adding, deleting nodes are standard operation that should not destroy data.

There is a bit of [documentation about this topic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/add-elasticsearch-nodes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch supports easy addition and removal of master and data nodes as a distributed database. You need to be careful about how you are adding or removing nodes to avoid split brain problem.
No data will be lost and will only be distributed if you enable shard replicaton.

See also: [How to add a new node to my Elasticsearch cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717790/how-to-add-a-new-node-to-my-elasticsearch-cluster)